# let $a,b,x,y$ be cardinal numbers such that $a \le b$ and $x \le y$, prove that $a^x \le b^y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $a,b,x,y$ be cardinal numbers such that $a \le b$ and $x \le y$, prove that $a^x \le b^y$.
let $\operatorname{card} A=a$, $\operatorname{card}B=b$, and so on.
From the given conditions I know there is an injection $g: A \to B$ and an injectipn $h: X \to Y$. But I can't find an injection from $A^X$ into $B^Y$ from this. How may I obtain such an injection to prove this result?

Comment: You can describe injections in $2$ steps, e.g. $A^X\to B^X\to B^Y$.

Answer (score 0):

For each function $\phi:X\to A$, you can define a function $\psi:Y\to B$, using your injections $g$ and $h$. For each $y\in\mathrm{im}(h)$, define $\psi(y)=g(\phi(h^{-1}(y)))$, and pick some arbitrary element in $B$ to send the rest of $Y$ to. The mapping that sends $\phi\mapsto\psi$ is injective; is it clear why?

Comment: Hmm. It was the $B^X\to B^Y$ step that used choice... Can a function be extended in an arbitrary way to a larger domain without choice?

Comment: Actually, there is no choice there since you only picked one element of $B$. But you do no need to consider the case $B = \emptyset$ separately, I think.

Comment: If $B$ is empty, then so is $A$, and in that case, $A^X=B^Y=0$, right?

Comment: $0^0 = 1$, but this comment is too short.